# Send messages from Jenkins to multiple Slack channels

Tags: jenkins, slack

According to the main [Jenkins-Slack documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin#install-instructions-for-slack) you have to configure the Jenkins app for slack and there you specify a single channel where the plugin can post. Now in my case, I need to post to multiple channels and users from a Jenkins server and it is very cumbersome to manage multiple auth tokens. Is there a way to have a single token that would work with all the channels and users? Are there other approaches? I see that the Jenkins plugin has a *bot* checkbox, but there is almost no documentation on how to make this work.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `channel: '#CHANNEL_NAME`:

More info: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/slack/

```
post {
    success {
      slackSend (channel: '#ch1', color: '#00FF00', message: "SUCCESSFUL: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]' (${env.BUILD_URL})")
    }

    failure {
      slackSend (channel: '#ch1', color: '#FF0000', message: "FAILED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]' (${env.BUILD_URL})")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just implemented the solution for my project channels.

There is an `Advanced` button available in the `Post build actions` -> `Slack notification of a Job`.

You can give the base URL and token along with the channel name you want to send the notifications to.

Comment: For more info and screenshots, see this solved issue of the slack-plugin. "Multiple teams in one jenkins" https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin/issues/111

Answer (score 1):

If one has enough permissions to their organization's slack account, one can create an app at https://api.slack.com/apps?new_app=1 which acts as a bot.

Once this bot is installed to workspace [ `https://api.slack.com/apps/<org-id>/install-on-team?` ] and was given permission to post to targeted channels
( just send a message `/invite @<bot-name>` in the channel and it will have permissions to post to that channel]. Not sure how to do it for users, though.

Apart from that, `slackSend` supports sending to multiple channels in a single go.

> Multiple channels may be provided as a **comma**, **semicolon**, or **space** delimited string.

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/slack/

For ex., any one of the following are valid:

```
channel: "#ch-1,#ch-2,#ch-3"

(OR)

channel: "#ch-1;#ch-2;#ch-3"

(OR)

channel: "#ch-1 #ch-2 #ch-3"
```

Full command may be as:

```
slackSend (channel: '#ch1 #ch2 #ch3', color: '#00FF00', message: "SUCCESSFUL: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]' (${env.BUILD_URL})")
```